# error in convert datetime from a text field

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I have a subquery which converts a text coloumn into datetime. Since it is in text format there are coloumns wich contains bad data. I know the first answer would be to correct the data, I strongly agree that. I do not have the privileges to do that, unfortunately i have to deal with it.

below is my query

```
INNER JOIN TABLE XYZ
ON XYZ.COLOUMN1=YZX.COLOUMN2
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ABC.stu_id
           ABC.stu_name
           CONVERT(DATETIME,LMN.startDate,111) STARTDATE
           CONVERT(DATETIME,LMN.endDate,111) ENDDATE
FROM STUDENT ABC
INNER JOIN AN_STUDENT_TABLE LMN
            ON ABC.stu_id=LMN.stu_id
WHERE ISDATE(startDate)=1
AND   ISDATE(endDate)=1
GROUP BY ABC.stu_id,ABC.stu_name,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) DIN  ON DIN.stu_id=LMNOP.stu_id
WHERE e.date BETWEEN DIN.STARTDATE AND DIN.ENDDATE
```

when i compare e.date with the startdate and enddate it fails giving me an well know error

```
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."
```

what can be done to atleast skip those bad data records which cannot be converted?
I tried my best to figure this out but failed. Any help/advice appretiated!

Comment: Don't use `CONVERT(DATETIME,LMN.startDate,111)` instead use `CONVERT(DATETIME,CASE WHEN ISDATE(LMN.startDate)=1 THEN LMN.startDate END,111)` and same for end date (and possibly `e.Date` if that is a string too)

Comment: Martin, I tried doing that today, but the value in the resultset is too less than expected. So i was trying to figure the bad data from that coloumns of startDate and endDate. I could find many of the date entered were (09/14/0210,01/23/1200,05/12/1212,09/25/1008,10/01/1001,01/23/1200,10/01/1007,01/01/0201)

Comment: I think i have to do a tedious job of finding out all the dates which have a bad data in it. :( Its going to take long time.        NO PAIN NO GAIN.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ISDATE` in the where clause does not necessarily filter out the bad dates before they are used in the conversion.

I think you should do this in two steps. First create a temp table or table variable that holds the rows from `STUDENT` where `startDate` and `endDate` is correct (use `ISDATE` for this) and then use that table in your actual query.

Comment: Eriksson i cant use the table variable as i am going to incule this code in my OLEDB data source in the SSIS package to generate an excel report.